# Docker does not send logs to fluentd when it runs in the same Docker Compose stack

Tags: docker, docker-compose, fluentd

I'm trying to use Fluentd in Docker Compose stack base on the tutorial https://docs.fluentd.org/container-deployment/docker-compose.

My stack is as follow:

```
version: '3'

services:
  one:
    image: alpine:3.10.2
    command: sh -c 'while true; do echo $$(hostname) - $$(date); sleep 2; done'
    depends_on:
      - fluentd
    logging:
      driver: "fluentd"
      options:
        fluentd-async-connect: 'true'
        fluentd-address: localhost:24224
        tag: service.one

  two:
    image: alpine:3.10.2
    command: sh -c 'while true; do echo $$(hostname) - $$(date); sleep 1; done'
    depends_on:
      - fluentd
    logging:
      driver: "fluentd"
      options:
        fluentd-async-connect: 'true'
        fluentd-address: localhost:24224
        tag: service.two

  fluentd:
    image: fluent/fluentd:v1.7-debian-1
    volumes:
      - ./fluentd/conf:/fluentd/etc
      - ./logs:/apps/logs
    ports:
      - "24224:24224"
      - "24224:24224/udp"
```

My `fluent.conf` is pretty simple:

```
<source>
    @type forward
    port 24224
    bind 0.0.0.0
</source>

<match **>
    @type stdout
</match>

<match *.*>
    @type file
    path /apps/logs/service.one/${tag}.%Y_%m_%d__%H-%M-%S.log
    # time_slice_format %Y%m%d
    # time_format %Y_%m_%d__%H-%M-%S

    <buffer tag,time>
        timekey 1d
        timekey_use_utc true
        flush_interval 30s
    </buffer>
</match>
```

I'm using

```
# Docker for Mac
$ docker -v                                 
Docker version 19.03.1, build 74b1e89
$ docker-compose -v 
docker-compose version 1.24.1, build 4667896b
```

When I start the stack with `docker-compose up -d`, the `fluentd` container does not receive any log from the other containers.

I discovered that if I started the `fluentd` **first** and then the others, the logging will work as expected. (Or `--force-recreate` the other containers work the same).

Does anyone encounter the same issue? Or `fluentd` is supposed to be used that way?

Thanks a lot for your time!

Comment: you can follow https://docs.docker.com/compose/startup-order/ as a workaround

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem is that you've got 2 `match` directives in the configuration and the first one blocks the second.

Try with this one:

```
<source>
    @type forward
    port 24224
    bind 0.0.0.0
</source>


<match *.*>
    @type copy
    <store>
        @type file
        path /apps/logs/temp/log.${tag}.txt
        # time_slice_format %Y%m%d
        # time_format %Y_%m_%d__%H-%M-%S

        <buffer tag, time>
            @type file
            path /apps/logs/${tag}/entry_%Y%m%d.log
            timekey 1m
            timekey_wait 30s
            timekey_use_utc true
        </buffer>
    </store>
    <store>
        @type stdout
    </store>
</match>
```

Comment: I did try this one. But even if I have only one `match *.* { @type stdout }`, the problem is the same.

Comment: I did use the setup you offered. The only differences have been: fluent.conf and the logs permissions set to 777 on the host since the uid/gid are different in the container.

Comment: I tried to put some changes in the code to flush the output to the files.

Answer (score 0):

@Genzer

I meet the same issue as yours, It seems like the fluentd service MUST BE READY before other service run.

You can control the serivces startup order by @LinPy's link

https://docs.docker.com/compose/startup-order/

Comment: Can you provide a reason/links that explains why it MUST BE READY?